# Is there a way to keep indentation when commenting out the control statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

In python, is there a way to keep the indentation of a block of code within the control statement when commenting out the control statement?

The use case would be a situation where you want to temporarily comment out an `if-statement`, but don't want to unindent the nested code. Am looking for a dummy control statement as follows:

Originally:

```
if condition is True:
    print('print')
```

Temporarily:

```
#if condition is True:
dummy_control_statement:
    print('print')
```

Comment: Something like: `if False and original-condition:`? Later, easily replace all `False and ` with empty string. Or just `if False:` if you prefer to comment out the original line of code.

Comment: Alternatively, just `if True:` would probably work, right?

Comment: @jarmod thanks that works nicely in my case. how do i mark the question answered on a comment

Comment: You don't. You can post your own answer if you wish.

Comment: Hi, I've added as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a couple of options that might work for you:

1. `if False and original-condition`: (easily replace all `False and`  with empty string to revert)
2. `if False:` (if you prefer to comment out the original line of code)